# How can I modify metadata for an existing Cloudflare R2 object?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

The goal is to modify HTTP metadata (specifically, cacheControl) for an existing Cloudflare R2 object.

According to [this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/runtime-apis/#http-metadata), it's possible to override the metadata when *returning* an object – useful, but this doesn't change what is stored in R2.

> *Generally, these fields match the HTTP metadata passed when the object was created. They can be overridden when issuing GET requests, in which case, the given values will be echoed back in the response.*

According to [this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/runtime-apis/#r2object-definition), it is of course possible to set metadata on `put()`. This is straightforward for an initial write, but unclear how it would behave if an object already exists. Could this be used to kind of "re-put()" an existing object? If key X is already present in R2 with metadata Y, is it allowed to perform a subsequent put() for X, but with new metadata Z?

> *R2Object is created when you PUT an object into an R2 bucket. R2Object represents the metadata of an object based on the information provided by the uploader. Every object that you PUT into an R2 bucket will have an R2Object created.*

I'm using a Worker in front of R2, so I can set the response using the R2 object contents, along with setting HTTP headers (ex: `headers: {'Cache-Control': '...'}`). This works for informing the browser of cache behavior, but leaves the existing object metadata unchanged in R2.

One option would be to "delete()" an existing object, and then "put()" it right back with any desired metadata included. This could work, though seems like an undesirable solution.

So, what are my options to update metadata for an existing object? Is it allowed to call "put()" again as a way to overwrite existing metadata? Is it better to delete first, then put? Is there some other mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the options are to either:

1. call "put" with the same object, this time including new updated metadata; or
2. delete the object first, then do #1

If there is in fact a way to update the metadata, it isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the existing file metadata from cloudflare r2 by using the **CopyObjectCommand**. On it's input include the **Metadata** attribute which is a Record<string,string> and attribute **MetadataDirective** equals to 'REPLACE'.

```js
   const input = {
            CopySource: copySource,
            Bucket: destinationBucket,
            Key: key,//filename
            Metadata : {
              "x-amz-meta-value1": "['e3dfa','*']",
              "x-amz-meta-value2": "fasdf"
            },
            MetadataDirective: 'REPLACE'
        };
        
       const command = new CopyObjectCommand(input);
       await S3.send(command);
```